# Can't open file APK issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, signed-apk

I have generated signed apk (android studio 2.3) and uploaded in site.I have successfully download but unable to open it from downloads app in device. I'm able to install from third party file explorer. This is weird behavior as im doing this from past 2 years and never faced this situation.Please help me out.

Key changes done in project

1) Updated Android Studio to 2.3

2) Gradle from 2.2.3 to 2.3

3) BuildToolsversion from 23.0.3 to 25

Comment: Imho, this is a restriction of your device's vendor

Comment: this is happened only after android studio updation. Maybe you are right but i want documentation on the same